# Copying and Paste Values into next empty Row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have recently started doing some work in Google Sheets, where previously I have been able to code functions in Excel, I am unable to get this working in Google Sheets Scripting.

I have two sheets

Sheet 1. Cells A1 - E5 contain values based on some selection criteria
Sheet 2. Register Sheet

What I need is when executing the script (via drawing and linked macro)

I need it to copy the range A1:E1

Go into Sheet 2, Go to the first Blank Cell in Column A, and then Paste Values.

I am using the following script, and I'm getting

> coordinates of the target range are outside of the dimensions of the sheet.

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("PNG Sheet!A1:E1");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Project Codes");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Graeme

Comment: Hmm.  When I test it on my sheet it works fine, UNLESS I try it when there are no more rows to paste into.  Then I get the error you get.  Have you tried adding more rows to your destination sheet?  Google sheets don't expand automatically.

Comment: @RonKloberdanz they do, but only in certain situations - such as using `setValues` with multiple row output. In general, you are correct - the sheet will not add rows.

Answer (score 3):

You're receiving this error because you're attempting to select a range in the "Project Codes" sheet that does not exist. Use instead the [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method, which will

1. paste the passed values into the first blank row, and
2. automatically resize your sheet.

   ```
   function moveValuesOnly() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var source = ss.getRange("PNG Sheet!A1:E1");
     var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Project Codes");
     destSheet.appendRow(source.getValues()[0]);
     source.clear();
   }
   ```

Comment: Worker perfectly.

Comment: @Diego, what if I need to transpose my row from the original sheet, and attach starting from some cell...i.e. not like a new column, please?

Comment: Hi @Olga, I recommend posting a new question if you can't find an answer elsewhere on the site. The question will get more visibility than this comment and someone may answer it before I have time to review it.